# Reading cookies on localhost

Tags: php, macos, cookies, localhost

i have installed phpmyadmin on mac but there are problem , when i using $_COOKIE[]  i see this message in my web page

> Notice: Undefined variable: coo in

how can i fix this problem ?

thank you .

Comment: cookies are enabled? you can check it with phpinfo();

Comment: Did you use `setcookie` function?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help:

First, you have to set a cookie value:

```
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", $expire);
?>
```

After that, you can retrieve this value:

```
<?php
// Print a cookie
echo $_COOKIE["user"];

// A way to view all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

> Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: user in /Library/WebServer/Documents/cookie.php on line 8 Array ( )

Answer (score 0):

***user1219391 :***

You can check if the cookie value exists using this code:

```
if (array_key_exists('user', $_COOKIE))
 {
     $userStatus=$_COOKIE['user'];
 }
 else
 {
     $userStatus='Not Set';
 }

 echo 'The value of Cookie user is '. $userStatus;
```

***With this you can solve your issue...***